# Dialogflow : followEventInput

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

I want to use follow-up intent. My user says something which launch an intent, send a response and launch another one, which sends a response and launch another one... I use those function

```
function send_message_follow(res,output,token,quote,id,action,parametre){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({
    "fulfillmentText" : output,
    "outputContexts": [ 
        {
            "name": id + "/contexts/connected",
            "lifespanCount": 5,
            "parameters": {
                "token": token, 
                "quote" : quote 
            }
        }
    ],
    "followupEventInput": {
        "name": action,
        "languageCode": "fr",
        "parameters": {
            "param": parametre,
        }
    }
}));`
```

`function send_message_final(res,output,token,quote,id){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
        "fulfillmentText" : output,
        "outputContexts": [ 
            {
                "name": id + "/contexts/connected",
                "lifespanCount": 5,
                "parameters": {
                    "token": token, 
                    "quote" : quote 
                }
            }
        ]
    }));`

However, output is not shown with send_message_follow. I works only with send_message_final. I could add the 1rst output as a parameter to catch for the other ones, but this shows only 1 block of message. I want 1 per intent.
Is there a way to fix this ? Thanks

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? it is a bit confusing. Update your question and put intents, and possibly user-bot conversation.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to "fix" this.  Follow up events are a way to redirect from the currently match intent to another intent.  The currently match intent does not have a chance to respond before it is redirected.  This means you will only have one response from the intent that is redirected to last.  You can't compile response from multiple intent responses by redirecting through multiple intents with follow up events.

When a followup event is triggered from the webhook, the event specified in the webhook response is triggered. Triggering the event through a webhook sends the request back through Dialogflow for matching without responding to the user. The response to the user is sent as if the user triggered the event that was triggered in the webhook.  After the second intent is matched by the event, Dialogflow will do any necessary work (like webhook calls or additional prompts for required parameters) and send a response back as if the second intent was the originally matched intent.

[image]

1. A user sends a request to Dialogflow.
2. "Intent 1" is matched by Dialogflow.
3. A webhook request is sent to your fulfillment server, which indicates that intent 1 was matched.
4. Your fulfillment server responds to the webhook request with a followup event response.
5. Dialogflow re-matches intent 2 based on the followup event sent in the webhook response.
6. Dialogflow sends a response to the user based solely on intent 2 being matched. Dialogflow may send another webhook call indicating intent 2 was matched, or send a prompt for unfulfilled required parameters (if configured) for intent 2.